# Express the length of the as a function of x

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I am having problems understanding how to extract this information into a formula.

`A 10-foot wall stands 5 feet from a building. A ladder, supported by the wall, touches a building. Express the length of the ladder as a function of x`

(Note: i do have have the answer to the question, my question is on how to extract the information)

Any help would be much appreciated, Cheers!

[image: This is a picture example of the problem]

Comment: What is $x$ here? A drawing would help!

Comment: ill draw one out, turns out you cant really draw one with the automatic formatting

Comment: OK, you can scan a paper drawing ...

Comment: @NickyHekster i have uploaded a picture

Comment: Similar triangles gives you 10 is to $x$ as $y$ is to $5+x$. Pythagoras gives you a relation involving $x,y,L$. Then eliminate $y$ to get a relation between $x$ and $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Pythagorean Theorem, we get: $L=\sqrt{y^2+(x+5)^2}$.

Now, we have to find a way to express $y$ in terms of $x$.

Notice that the two triangles in the diagram are similar triangles. This means that the ratio of two sides in the first triangle has to be equal to the ratio of the corresponding sides in the second triangle:

$$\frac{x}{10}=\frac{x+5}{y}$$

By cross-multiplication, we find: $y=\frac{10(x+5)}{x}$.

Hence, we can express the length of $L$ by:

$$L=\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{10(x+5)}{x}\bigg)^2+(x+5)^2}$$

Comment: How do you get $x=y$ from $x/10=(x+5)/y$?

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I corrected the mistake.

Comment: Thank you, this is much clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Which information are you trying to extract?

Assuming the question as given actually gave that x is the distance from the bottom of the ladder to the bottom of the wall, there are 4 pieces of information:
1) There is a 10 foot wall
2) The wall if 5 feet from the building
3) The ladder touches both the wall and  the building
4) The distance from the bottom of the ladder to the bottom of the wall is x feet.

This is then enough information to produce the diagram given.

If you wish to solve the problem, I would then note that
$$L^2 = y^2 + (x+5)^2$$ by pythagoras,
And
$$\frac{y}{5+x} = \frac{10}{x}$$
As they are similar triangles.